# Elasticsearch not indexing all documents

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to index all my files stored in MongoDB using Elasticsearch. But only 180842 files are indexed whereas I have 1637870 files in my DB. Any idea why not all documents are indexed?

I checked Elasticsearch log files and there is no error. But I found the below lines in my log file.

```
(1) [2013-09-11 02:20:57,539][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] [Arsenic] [mongodb][mongodb] Add attachment: 522bef23649dd3bb06a61fd8
(2) [2013-09-11 02:20:57,539][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver$Indexer] Add Attachment: 522bef0fe819cc4b70875a48 to index mongoindex / type files
(3) [2013-09-11 02:20:57,539][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] [Arsenic] [mongodb][mongodb] Caught file: 522bef230eb5b705cf8ccd91 - /data/Test.java
```

Line (2) means that the file is added to my index. Am not sure what Line (1) and (3) means. Does that mean that those files are not added to index?

**NOTE** I used the below code to create index:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "db": "submission_data",
    "collection": "fs",
    "gridfs": true
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "mongoindex",
    "type": "files"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually its because ur oplog size is small. its a capped collection.if you increase your oplog size then it ll work..!

Comment: i also faced same prob.And i found a solution its beacause if you mention size as 100 for oplog den it ll delete old log.so when running via river it only consider oplog only.so it ll index partial object. refer capped collection and oplog.rs of mongo..!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you have a lot of collections try to index one at a time and then restart elasticsearch.
Disable the gridfs and have a look on how I made the indexes on mongodb:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/mongosearch/_meta" -d '
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers":
    [
      { "host": "localhost", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "options": { "secondary_read_preference": false },
    "db": "mydbname",
    "collection": "users",
    "gridfs": false
    },
    "index": {
      "name": "mongosearch",
      "type":   "users"  }
}'
```

**EDIT:**
The above script does the following:

1. Tell that the index is named mongosearch.
2. Define the server that runs at localhost in port 27017.
3. Dont river shards (secondary read preference).
4. The name of the database is nydbname.
5. The collection that will go to index is the users collection. '
6. [gridfs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is something about storing documents.
7. Finally we define the index name again and tell the type of collection that we want to index.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. My problem is I have all the files in same collection. Also could you please give me more explanation on what the above index does?

Comment: Thanks much! I tried your way and still it is not working. Steps followed:  (1) I created 10 databases and then I divided my files and placed 150,000 files in fs.files collection of each database.  (2) Then I tried to index files in each db individually.  (3) I used the same index you gave but I have set the gridFS to "true". As I am indexing files placed in gridFS it is not working if I make gridFS "false".  I have no problem in indexing my first 150,000 files. When I tried to index my next 150,000 files, it stops after indexing 80,000 files.